# WebStorm, unable to debug NPM scripts?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Using WebStorm, I am able to run my Express server using my NPM script. When I right click on the npm `dev` script and select `Run 'dev'`, the server starts as expected.

[image]

[image]

---

But when I select `debug 'dev'` the server does not start:

[image]

[image]

This is my `dev` script from my `package.json`:

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js",
```

Comment: did you try removing `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` from the script? as it's written in the error message, it's no longer required.

Comment: also, the officially supported way to debug applications started with nodemon is using  *Attach to a Node.js/Chrome* debug configuration - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#nodemon

Comment: thanks, I followed the instructions from your link. when I start my application, I get the expected log: '[nodemon] starting node --inspect server.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/e5c30c59-a29e-40db-a81d-b338e1dfbd71'. And then I start the `attach to a node/chrome debug configuration`, but the app doesn't stop on my breakpoints?

Comment: it works for me.. try using `--inspect-brk` instead of `--inspect` to make sure that the execution is suspended until the debugger is attached - does it make any difference?

Comment: thanks, it's working for me now